# While I am installing cryptography in django project using pycharm, I got the error. Failed building wheel for cryptography

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, windows, pycharm

While I am installing cryptography got the following error.

```
Failed building wheel for cryptography
Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

i was have same problem

my config was : `python==3.7` `django==2.2` `pip==19.0.3`

and its not from `pycharm`

its from `pip`

just upgrade `pip` to `21.0.1`

- Update:

some error code:

```
running build_rust

=============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================
If you are seeing a compilation error please try the following steps to
successfully install cryptography:
1) Upgrade to the latest pip and try again. This will fix errors for most
users. See: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/#upgrading-pip
2) Read https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html for specific
instructions for your platform.
3) Check our frequently asked questions for more information:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/faq.html
4) Ensure you have a recent Rust toolchain installed:
https://cryptography.io/en/latest/installation.html#rust
5) If you are experiencing issues with Rust for *this release only* you may
set the environment variable `CRYPTOGRAPHY_DONT_BUILD_RUST=1`.
=============================DEBUG ASSISTANCE=============================


error: Can not find Rust compiler

----------------------------------------
Running setup.py clean for cryptography
Failed to build cryptography

Failed building wheel for cryptography
Could not build wheels for cryptography which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```